# Proper way to Handle Nulls in ETL Process - SSIS or SQL Statement

Tags: sql-server, ssis

If you have an `SSIS` connection handling `SOURCE` database connection pulling data from a `SQL` Statement.

Would it be more efficient to do `ISNULL` on the columns coming in via the `SQL` statement, or to do a `Derived Column` and check for each applicable column for a NULL value in the expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's more efficient to convert in the query.

This article has explains the performance impacts of different types and methods of data conversions in Integration Services.

"In terms of overall performance (elapsed time and CPU utilization), performing the data type conversion in the OLE DB layer instead of using Integration Services is the fastest option. Note that the Data Conversion transformation has a run time very similar to the run time of SQL Server’s own data conversion – although it spends more CPU to do the same work..."

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2009/12/01/draft-performance-comparison-between-data-type-conversion-techniques-in-ssis-2008.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Jason Is this solution scalable? Meaning is it the same if I'm selecting 3-6 thousand rows vs 3-6 million?

Comment: Presumably this also depends on the relative capabilities of the source server and the SSIS server, if they're separate machines, though I doubt there's much to choose in CPU time with a simple ISNULL... (Also, if you have a million NULLs and you're turning them into "UNKNOWN VALUE", it might slow things down if your flow *then* transfers them over a network...)

Answer (score 1):

In your example it should be.

With simple conversions, the differences between a derived column transformation and using a t-sql are going to be marginal (t-sql being slightly faster). From my experience, most of the additional overhead in ssis comes from the size of the data set and the type and number of tasks you are using.

Also, if you are adding the derived column transformation just for this column I would do the conversion in T-SQL and exclude the additional data flow task altogether.

What are you doing with the records once you determine which ones are null? If your excluding null records, I would use T-SQL.